# How to silently/automatically install Desktop Experience in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I need to install Desktop Experience in Azure Worker Role. Installing DE via the command line can be done with:

```
c:\servermanagercmd -install Desktop-Experience
```

And then a reboot is required.

How can I best make this work in Azure Worker Role?

---

UPDATE:

1) Make sure to use OS Family 2 and SDK >=1.3

2) Use elevated startup task to call included batchfile with this command:

```
3) servermanagercmd -install Desktop-Experience -restart -resultPath results.xml
```

---

I have tried

a) to put that commandline in a batch/.cmd file and run it via an elevated startup task. Result: The worker role keeps Aborting and restarts in a neverending loop.

b) I have tried to create a new Process() in OnStart(), under elevated runtime, something like this:

ServiceDefinition.csdef:

```
 Runtime executionContext="elevated"
```

WorkerRole.cs:

```
public override bool OnStart()
{
   if (!System.IO.File.Exists("Startup\\InstallationFinished.txt"))
   {

      Process startup = new Process(); 

      startup.StartInfo.FileName = "Startup\\InstallDesktopExperience.cmd";
      startup.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
      startup.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
      startup.Start();
      startup.WaitForExit();

      System.IO.File.WriteAllText("Startup\\InstallationFinished.txt", 
            "Installation is complete.");

      startup.StartInfo.FileName = "Startup\\Reboot.cmd";
      startup.Start();
    }

    base.OnStart(); 
}
```

InstallDesktopExperience.cmd:

```
servermanagercmd -install Desktop-Experience
```

Reboot.cmd:

```
shutdown /r
```

The result is that the Event Viewer in the Azure Worker Role shows an exception from TrustedInstaller (0xc0000005). After this error is shown in the event log, DE cannot be installed manually by opening a command line window and typing the command either. I get the error:

Error: Installation of [Desktop Experience] failed. Attempt to install Desktop Experience failed with error code 0x80080005.  Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))

(but it works by doing it manually in a command line window if I haven't run the code in OnStart)

I'm lost. Thanks in advance for any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You should reference this guide from Wage Wegner.  It deals with Expression Encoder, but the prereq of Desktop Experience is exactly the same:

http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/01/using-expression-encoder-4-in-a-windows-azure-worker-role/

---

Snippet from the same, but you should take the time to read his explanation on some of these concepts

```
REM : Install the Desktop Experience
ServerManagerCMD.exe -install Desktop-Experience -restart -resultPath results.xml
REM : Make a folder for the AppData
md "%~dp0appdata"
REM : Change the location of the Local AppData
reg add "hku\.default\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\user shell folders" /v "Local AppData" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%~dp0appdata" /f
REM : Install Encoder
"%~dp0\webpicmd\WebPICmdLine.exe" /accepteula /Products: ExpressionEncoder4 /log:encoder.txt
REM : Change the location of the Local AppData back to default
reg add "hku\.default\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\explorer\user shell folders" /v "Local AppData" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %%USERPROFILE%%\AppData\Local /f
REM : Exit gracefully
exit /b 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the link. But I still cannot get it to work. I see that he's also using servermanagercmd -install Desktop-Experience, but with the addition of the "-restart" option which I had not yet tried. I have created a new Azure project which only starts the elevated startup task with "servermanagercmd -install Desktop-Experience -restart". If I set taskType = "simple", then the worker role instance keeps Aborting and trying to restart in a never ending loop. If I set tasktype = "background", then the instance eventually becomes Ready, but

Comment: desktop experience has NOT been installed and the Event Viewer shows several errors in the Application log: Faulting application TrustedInstaller.exe, version 6.0.6002.18005, time stamp 0x49e025c2, faulting module wmicmiplugin.dll, version 6.0.6002.18342, time stamp 0x4cd53a17, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x0000000000038a60, process id 0xa58, application start time 0x01cbd9b873a148f0.  If someone wants to take a look at what's going on then you can download the bare bones Azure project from here: http://www.filedropper.com/desktopexperiencetest

Comment: I can also note that when opening Server Manager after the RDP works and the startup task has been run, then the server manager is unable to refresh/show the Roles Summary and the Features Summary. It just shows "Error" and at the bottom: "Last refresh: Failed". Obviously, something is going very wrong due to some unknown reason...

Comment: I notice that I'm on OS family 1, so that's probably the reason. Trying OS family 2 now and hoping for better luck. Since I'm new to Azure and starting out with SDK 1.3 right from the get go I didn't pay attention to the OS family since I figured I would be running the latest version of everything as default (but feeling a bit stupid since I did not notice that issue).

Comment: Yeah, I was gonna say upgrade to 1.3 and OS 2 (2008 R2) and give it a whirl.  I don't think the startup tasks and fulltrust even work 100% on OS 1

Comment: It worked with OS family 2, however it did not work when using taskType = "simple" (it kept Initalizing, waiting for host, forever). It worked with taskType="background" (haven't tried foreground), although it took a very long time from starting publishing until Ready - 20-25 minutes. I will try with taskType="simple" again just to be sure. Anyway, thanks for your help!